# Vertical centering of a title within a box which ignores possible accents

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes

I am currently adapting the `\part` command to customize the table of contents as follows [code directly extracted from the `book.cls` class]:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
      \setlength\fboxsep{2pt}%
      \noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][][c]{\ecart}%
      {\color{ocre!70}\bfseries\protect\centering\thepart}}\hskip6pt\colorbox{ocre!40}%
      {\strut\protect\parbox[c][][c]{\linewidth-4\fboxsep-\ecart-6pt}{\color{white}%
      \protect\centering\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}{#1}}%
    \else%
...
```

I am not providing the rest of the code which is quite long but the result is shown below:
[image]

It is quite clear that the accented letter `è` affects the vertical alignment of the title within its box. Is there a way to avoid that? I would be happy with a vertical alignment that ignores accented letters. Otherwise, the `\vphantom` command is a possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to test without a working example but normally the `\strut` would be enough to cover the accented letters however you have used `\parbox[c]` so the text is vertically centred so moves down if accents are added. If you used `[b]` or `[t]` (which are the same for a one line box) then the text would align on the baseline so not move when there is an accent.

Alternatively you can hide the vertical size of the content by adding `\smash`

```
\leavevmode\protect\smash{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

Comment: yes, but I want to keep the vertically centred title so the `[c]` option is fine. I just would like the accent to be ignored by the vertical alignment.

Comment: OK, adding plan b...

Comment: ok, thanks. I tried but it yields quite unexpected results.   It looks to me that the `\vphantom{Ép}` command associated with a `\parbox[b][][b]{...}` command aligning at the bottom is a good compromise. I wanted to avoid the `\vphantom` but it probably cannot be avoided.

Comment: You are using the form of `\parbox` where you specify the height but not specifying the height, is that intended?

Comment: good question. I am not sure why I use this version. I thought it was the only one?

Comment: @pluton LaTeX arguments in `[]` are always optional. I just looked at the source and in fact it doesn't return an error in that case but only by luck: the actual processing is quite bizarre if you put an empty argument there. (I wrote that bit so I can say with some confidence that that use wasn't planned or tested:-) just remove the `[][b]` should be the same output I think.

Comment: Correct, same output. This is all good then. Thanks